# How can I disable combobox before button clicked in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm, combobox, disable

In my project I have a "Generate Reports" `Button` and a "Select Location" `ComboBox`. I want the user to be unable to choose a location before clicking
"Generate Report" `Button`.
the xaml containing the combobox and the button:

```xml
<Button Content="Generate Reports" Command="{Binding GenerateReportsCommand}" Height="36" Margin="4" />
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"   ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LocationFilterCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

What can I do in the ViewModel or UI? Thank you for all your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you know how to use data binding (based on your post you already use it).

Create a new Boolean in your ViewModel and bind the ComboBox's `IsEnabled` to it. (Something like `IsEnabled="{Binding YOURBOOLEAN}"`)

Update that Boolean from your `GenerateReportsCommand` after the user successfully generated the report. If you set that variable to true, the `ComboBox`'s `IsEnabled` will also be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an additional property inside the ViewModel.

```cs
private bool _areReportsGenerated = false;
public bool AreReportsGenerated
{
    get => _areReportsGenerated;
    set
    {
        _areReportsGenerated = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); // you method's implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

}
```

If you don't have an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged you can take a look at [Microsoft one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8).

Inside `GenerateReportsCommand` you should set `AreReportsGenerated` to `true`.

In the xaml then you only have to bind the newly created property to the `IsEnabled` property of the `ComboBox`

```xml
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"   ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}" IsEnabled="{Binding AreReportsGenerated}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LocationFilterCommand}" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

It should work.

I hope I was helpful.